# Command Phase Execution Failed: No such file or Directory in Dervice Data Xcode 14.3.1 in Mac M1 Pro

Tags: xcode, apple-m1

I am keep getting random error on my Macbook M1 Pro. While its working fine for my other Teammates, I used to get random compile error with the framework added in our project. as of now I am getting error as " in my Dervice data no such file found in path "SourcePackages/artifacts/FullStory/tools/FullStoryCommandLine: No such file or directory""

Its weird error I got for different Libraries randomly. Can anyone help me with that?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache or something?

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the Pods script.
Location of your script is "${PODS_ROOT}/Target Support Files/Pods-{SchemaName}/Pods-{SchemaName}-frameworks.sh"
Replace line 44

```
source="$(readlink "${source}")"
```

with

```
source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
```